# Cannot enable automatic login in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, login, automatic

I am not able to enable automatic login in Ubuntu 22.04 when I press or activate the button. Shortly after it is misconfigured again. How to solve it to leave it activated permanently?

ubuntu-22.04

Answer (score 1):

sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

```
# Enabling automatic login
AutomaticLoginEnable = true
AutomaticLogin = user1

# Enabling timed login
TimedLoginEnable = true
TimedLogin = user1
TimedLoginDelay = 10
```

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and then hit <kbd>Y</kbd> then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

reboot

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please use the {_} icon above the edit window to format `code` as above.

Comment: New here. Thank you.

Comment: I don't have gdm3. Do I just create it and custom.conf file?